# "Use of unresolved identifier" with CoreMLModel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, coreml

For some background: I'm using Swift 4 and Xcode 9 (beta). I'm trying to implement a CoreML Model in my app, however, for this line of code (which was placed in an IBAction func in my ViewController class):

```
let coreMLModel = testmodel2().model
```

I get an error that says "Use of unresolved identifier 'testmodel2'". I've read some of the other similar questions for this, and I made sure that my ViewController and my testmodel2.mlmodel file have the same target. Nothing else seems to be working.

Comment: I know, my advice is like from Captain Obvious, but I just had the same problem a minute ago. Deleted and then re-added model file to the project and it started working.

Comment: Did you remove the model to trash or just remove the reference to it? I've tried this before and it's caused issues with the target membership and location.

Comment: I only removed the reference to it and then drag-and-dropped it back.

Answer (score 8):

For me to work 100% of the time I had to change the compile language for the CoreML model in Build Settings to Swift instead of automatic. Automatic always compiled an objective-c class and somehow my Swift code couldn't access it.

Comment: I can affirm this. It is the only solution that really worked for me. All 'add file again' solutions are buggy

Answer (score 4):

You missed to add it to **Compile Sources**

1 : drag model file in you project and copy it there

2 : go to **Build Phases**

3 : open **Compile Sources**

4 : Click on **+** and add your model there

now model should be available in your project

[image]

Comment: Issue not resolved after adding the respective model also, Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me. I trashed the file from the project, imported it back and checked the Target Membership again. It worked.

[image]

Found my answer here: [Why is Inceptionv3 Machine Learning model not recognized on my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345873/why-is-inceptionv3-machine-learning-model-not-recognized-on-my-project)

Answer (score 2):

While importing mlmodel into a Objective C project with Swift brigding header , than you had change the compile Language for CoreML from project build Setting from Automatic to Swift as shown in the picture[image]