# Why is Inceptionv3 Machine Learning model not recognized on my project?

Tags: swift, machine-learning, image-recognition

I am building a basic image recognition app in Swift using the Inception v3 Machine Learning model.
I dragged and dropped the Inceptionv3.mlmodel inside my project folder and made sure the "Copy items if needed" option was ticked.

Inside the detect function:

```
func detect(image: CIImage) {

    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Inceptionv3().model) else {
        fatalError("Loading CoreML Model Failed!")
    }

    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (request, error) in
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else {
            fatalError("Model failed to process")
    }

        if let firstResult = results.first {
            self.navigationItem.title = firstResult.identifier
        }

}
```

I get the following message:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Inceptionv3'

Also when I click on the Inceptionv3.mlmodel file on my project browser I get this message:

> Interface generation only available with valid target

But I know it should read something like:

> Inceptionv3 (Swift generated source)

With a small arrow next to it that allow you to access the class.

Any ideas?

Comment: I faced the same problem. Drag and drop is not working in Xcode currently for some reason. When I tried to add the model by right click and selecting "Add files to project" then it generated the interfaces correclty.

Comment: @GudlaSrinivas same issue here and solved with your tip, please consider answering the question to keep it here.

Comment: I had this bug pop up once I decided to add some obj-c files to my project.  Did you do something similar?

Comment: I have the original version of this project, and the expanded version.  In the expanded version I added some Obj-C files to my project.  When I click on the inceptionv3 of the original project it says: "Automatically generated Swift model class".  On the expanded version where I added extra files, it changed to: Automatically generated Objective-C model class.  If you have the latter, you need to add inceptionv3.h to your bridge header file. What does your model class read as?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved by add inceptionv3 in bridging header.

Comment: This is true if you you click on your inceptionv3 model and it reads: Automatically generated Objective-C model class.  You actually have to add "inceptionv3.h" to your bridging header.

Comment: can you provide sample code on how to add a bridging header?

Answer (score 11):

make sure that your target membership is checked.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, unfortunately it is still not working. I will post if I get it solved.

Answer (score 2):

Seems some sort of bug. This might help, Remove the file reference and try adding it again.

This worked for me. Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by the file reference?

Comment: Just right click the file to 'delete' it. When prompted, click 'Remove Reference' button

Comment: At the time i was using Xcode beta. So hopefully this must be fixed now by Apple

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Drag and Drop, Right click the project and click "Add Files To Project". Then add the model files. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cannot have the line of code existing before you import the model file.

Delete the model file, remove the references when it asks. Now add back the model library file. Go back to the commented line of code and directly under type the same line of code and allow xcode to predict you want use the 'Incepetionv3' model file. The error will now go away.

Xcode doesn’t like cut and paste lines of code when there is a reference to a file but more importantly the file has to exist before the line of code is written.